# Jekyll does not modify files

Tags: jekyll

I have a simple `index.html` which contains just `{% include t.html %}`

It is copied to `_site` as is, without substituting `_includes/t.html`

Other substitutions `{{ }}` do not work as well. How to debug and fix that?

Comment: Does the file have the [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/)? That's what causes Jekyll to process it. Please post the templates you are using and their output.

Comment: Thanks! I missed that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, if this question is already solved, please help contribute by answering your own question and marking it as answered! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One should add the [front matter](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/frontmatter/) to the file to make Jekyll process it.